# When is the etale cohomology of a surface free?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth variety over $\mathbb{F}_q$, $\ell$ a prime prime to $q$. I learned that if $X$ is a curve then $H_c^i(X,\mathbb{Z}_{\ell})$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}$-module.

When $X$ is of a higher dimension, is there some general condition that can be added to $X$ so that the same conclusion holds? (I am primarily interested in the case that $X$ is a surface.)

Comment: Note that the answer for general $X$ will depend on $\ell$. In fact, Gabber proved that is $X$ is smooth projective, then for almost all $\ell$ the cohomology $H^i(X,\mathbb Z_\ell)$ is torsion free. (In characteristic $0$ this easily follows from comparison with singular cohomology; the proof in characteristic $p$ uses the deep 'gcd theorem' [Weil II, Thm. 4.5.1] from Deligne's work on the Weil conjectures.) It seems likely that this implies a similar statement for $X$ smooth quasi-projective.

Comment: Thus, if you want to know torsion-freeness for *all* $\ell$, this is morally equivalent to the question whether the singular cohomology of a smooth (projective) complex surface is torsion free. There is probably no easy condition on the surface that implies this.

Comment: Note that in char 0, $H^3_{tors} = H^2_{tors} = (H_1)_{tors} = (\pi_1^{ab})_{tors}$. An example with torsion is an Enriques surface, where $\pi_1 = \mathbb{Z}/2$

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn This sounds exactly what I need! Could you elaborate more details on the quasi-projective case?

Comment: It seems that my last statement was a bit rash. The argument for the quasi-projective case I had in mind doesn't work even if $U \subseteq X$ is the complement of a smooth closed subscheme $Z$. The idea is to use the long exact sequence (in general: some sort of dévissage). However, it is not true that if each two out of three are torsion-free, then so are the others. It seems that the result for smooth quasi-projective varieties requires a deeper insight (even in the case where $U$ has a smooth compactification with smooth boundary).

Comment: The Gabber reference is *Sur la torsion dans la cohomologie $\ell$-adique d’une variété,* C. R. Acad. Sci., Paris, Sér. I **297(1)** (1983), p. 179-182. It is [available online](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6248448g/f99.image.r=%22sur%20la%20torsion%20dans%20la%20cohomologie%22?rk=42918;4) through the Bibliothèque nationale de France.